How to make Collection sockets working in addon panel?
I can´t figure out how to enable editing collection inputs in N-panel. Thanks for any help


Could you Post a mwe?

Hello, please insert your code using tye website's code formatting tools. Showing more of your code - at least all that concerns these ui elements and their data and usage - would help seeing what's going on.

Hello, this is a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/317739/86891
